# InvalidCastException .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

[Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaJqY.png)

```
Dim Total As Decimal
Dim Price(1, 1) As Decimal
Price(0, 0) = TxtHoursGFX.Text
Price(0, 1) = TxtHoursWeb.Text
Price(1, 0) = TxtHoursGame.Text
Price(1, 1) = TxtHoursVideo.Text

Total = Price(0, 0) + Price(0, 1) + Price(1, 0) + Price(1, 1) + 25

LboxTotal.Items.Add(Price(0, 0) * 25)
LboxTotal.Items.Add(Price(0, 1) * 30)
LboxTotal.Items.Add(Price(1, 0) * 35)
LboxTotal.Items.Add(Price(1, 1) * 27)
LboxTotal.Items.Add(Total)

If TxtHoursGFX.Text = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Value")
ElseIf TxtHoursWeb.Text = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Value")
ElseIf TxtHoursGame.Text = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Value")
ElseIf TxtHoursVideo.Text = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Value")
End If
```

When i try empty error handlers with Integer data types they break everytime, i feel my college tutor hasn't explained this properly how do i fix this

Comment: You have an array of decimals and you are trying to push a string into that array. The error is self explanatory. You have to convert that string to a decimal first and push that to the array.

Comment: I can't fluently speak VB, but if this was C# (very related), I'd say `Price[0,0] = decimal.Parse(TxtHoursGFX.Text);` - essentially you need to parse the `string` as a `decimal`; the translation *might* just be `Decimal.Parse` :)

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`. You'll have an immediate *visual* of the problem. Correct as already commented.

Comment: The validation code you added is too late, it has to be moved in front of the Price() assignment.  Use Decimal.TryParse() instead of leaving it up to the vb.net compiler to generate the code to make the conversion from text to decimal.  TryParse() returns False when it can't understand what the user entered in the textbox.

Comment: The TxtHoursGFX.Text is an empty string "" that cannot be converted to decimal. You need to add some validation before doing the operation. You have to make sure that the textbox contains a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate/convert your string to decimal.  You could do something like this:

```
    'You'll probably want to clear the old items out every time you run whatever it is to calculate the total.
    LboxTotal.Items.Clear()

    Dim Total As Decimal
    Dim Price(1, 1) As Decimal

    Dim GFX, Web, Game, Video As Decimal

    'Parse the decimals from the string in each textbox.
    Decimal.TryParse(TxtHoursGFX.Text, GFX)
    Decimal.TryParse(TxtHoursWeb.Text, Web)
    Decimal.TryParse(TxtHoursGame.Text, Game)
    Decimal.TryParse(TxtHoursVideo.Text, Video)

    Price(0, 0) = GFX
    Price(0, 1) = Web
    Price(1, 0) = Game
    Price(1, 1) = Video


    Total = Price(0, 0) + Price(0, 1) + Price(1, 0) + Price(1, 1) + 25

    LboxTotal.Items.Add(Price(0, 0) * 25)
    LboxTotal.Items.Add(Price(0, 1) * 30)
    LboxTotal.Items.Add(Price(1, 0) * 35)
    LboxTotal.Items.Add(Price(1, 1) * 27)
    LboxTotal.Items.Add(Total)
```

Comment: This works because when you declare the variables GFX, Web, Game, Video As Decimal they are set to zero. Even if TryParse fails and returns False the variables have a numeric value and can be added and multiplied.